# Python threading - Handling threads when main thread raises an exception

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-multithreading

I have a thread that reads data from a data acquisition device. When my main function crashes, it doesn't kill the data acquisition thread. How can I stop the data acquisition if there's an exception outside the thread?

A simplified version of my program is:

```
class Daq_reader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.keepReading = True
        self.data = []

    def acquire(self):
        while self.keepReading:
            self.data = append_new_data(data)
            time.sleep(1)

def main():
    reader = Daq_reader()
    daq_thread = threading.Thread(target=reader.acquire, daemon=True)
    daq_thread.start()

    # rest of program here that might crash
```

I tried with daemon being True and False. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you want to kill your thread. You can use `python-worker` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/)) to create and abort the worker.

```
from worker import worker

class Daq_reader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.keepReading = True
        self.data = []

    @worker
    def acquire(self):
        while self.keepReading:
            self.data = append_new_data(data)
            time.sleep(1)

def main():
    try:
        reader = Daq_reader()
        reader_woker = reader.acquire()
    except:
        reader_woker.abort()
```

your `reader.acquire()` will be run in your background automatically when you decorate it with `@worker`